# This question should not have been closed once, let alone twice

Tags: support, closing

The question [How can I implement currency on my server?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/142111/how-can-you-get-money) has been closed not once, but twice. Apparently by people who don't play on Bukkit servers or participate in the wider Minecraft discussion communities? The asker is very evidently confused, but they are also very clearly – to those who have played on Minecraft servers – describing the effect of one of the variety of economy plugins for CraftBukkit such as iConomy.

It was very quickly reopened by users who were not at all confused by the question. It should not have been reclosed, and should now be reopened.

Comment: It was closed because it was unclear, then edited based on assumptions, which made it clear, but possibly not even the same question, then reverted to the unclear original and closed again.

Comment: The assumption that it was closed by people who don't understand is specious and insulting to the extreme.

Comment: @fbueckert The people who closed it clearly don't understand it, having voted as "unclear". And yet it is clear with the necessary information. QED?

Comment: Combined, the closing users have over 500 votes in [tag:Minecraft]. That doesn't sound like people who don't understand.

Comment: @SaintWacko I know how it went down, since I was watching it. The edit was good: they're clearly talking about adding an economy system. The asker didn't know this used plugins though, so they were confused. People who recognised what they were talking about were not confused at all though, and rewrote it.

Comment: You're **assuming** that's what the asker is asking about.  We have zero proof one way or the other that it's true.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Where did you get the necessary information? I haven't seen the asker post any clarifications.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: I understood the gist of what he wanted, but the lack of details makes the question completely unanswerable, unless you're willing to list _every single way_ of creating an economy on a Minecraft server.

Comment: Instead of getting myself banned for language, I'm just going to say I'm tired of this community's dynamic around close votes and request a voluntary sabbatical-ban.

Answer (score 11):

As much as I don't want to throw names around - I asked our #1 Minecraft answerer (fredley) whether the edit made that resulted in the reopening of the question fundamentally changed the meaning of the question and he said **yes** - thereby invalidating your opinion that the actions were taken "by people who don't play on Bukkit servers or participate in the wider Minecraft discussion".

Edits that fundamentally change the meaning of the question are generally frowned upon. The edit was the action that resulted in the question being reopened and as such, rolling it back ended up with the question getting closed again.

Since (according to the discussion in chat) there were multiple different things the asker could have been asking about based on the *very* limited information provided in the original question, it would be **better to wait until the asker comes back to clarify exactly what they're talking about rather than make assumptions** and hijack their question, resulting in an answer to something they didn't ask or weren't interested in.

Until such time the asker returns, it is in fact unclear what is being asked, and the question has been handled as such.

Comment: I don't get it. Why is it unclear? All the necessary information is there: "Minecraft, Currency, Servers. How?" If it's anything it's too broad, but not 'unclear'

Comment: @Robotnik: Approaching this from a problem solving standpoint, it _should_ be obvious that the root problem is not understood.  Therefore, any solution that's provided is based on a guess of what that problem is.  Similar problem definitions can (and often do) have wildly different root causes, each requiring a different solution.

Comment: @MBraedley - You said it yourself: *"unless you're willing to list every single way of creating an economy on a Minecraft server".* Like I said, it's answerable, but it sounds like 'Too broad' to me

Comment: @Robotnik: Personally, instead of providing a wall of text that's more than likely to frustrate the OP (and anyone else reading it), I'd prefer to understand what the OP really means.  That's an issue of clarity, not breadth.

Comment: That's my point. It's perfectly clear to me that the OP wants a currency/economy like system in Minecraft. However, listing every possible way is disingenious, and not good for our format.

Comment: @Robotnik: Huh, somehow I glossed over that last sentence in the first comment.  Still, my approach to most questions on Arqade (and many other sites on the network) means I need to understand the problem in order to solve it, not understand the question in order to answer it.  In this case, we have a situation where it's not precise enough to solve and too broad to answer.  Two sides of the same coin.

Comment: @MBraedley eh, don't mind me, I'm just nitpicking the close reason. In any case we're in agreement, until we're given more info by the OP, it should be closed

Comment: As the person who made the edit (I believe, unless further edits have been made since then that better tried to explain the question), I fully understand.  The initial problem with the question was that it was incredibly vague, and the edit tried to shed a little direction on the question without taking away too much of the original poster's intent...but I suspect, without further input from that poster, that further clarifying the question will be difficult, if not impossible.

Comment: I believe i edited it. The problem here is (like with many questions that get closed) that the questioner does not know as much as some people here do (he was asking for a cheat to enable money). And therefor cannot possibly be expected to put up a valid question (since that requires more knowledge). A simple answer would be to tell him to use mods and list 2 or 3 of those with some pro's cons. There are countless of issues like this on SE and somehow particularly on Arqade.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it should have.  As I said in my comment (which has been deleted), it lacks details required to properly answer the question.  Extremely vague references are made to what he wants to do, but there are no specifics.  Everyone who wanted it reopened seemed to think that it was a mod this guy was having trouble installing, but there's **absolutely no evidence for that!**

It could have been a Bukkit plugin (he said it's on a server), a client only mod (highly unlikely, but roll with it), or something completely vanilla (think SethBling/Etho store).  Hell, he could have thought it was vanilla when he (presumably) saw it someplace else, and not realized it was a mod.  *We just don't know.*  If you assume it's one thing (which is what the edit was doing), you make an ass out of you and me.

In the same comment that was deleted, I said I'd cast a reopen vote if the question was cleaned up.  I didn't mean for someone to completely mangle the original post, I meant for the OP to come back and clarify what he meant.  I imply that with the comment I left that's still there.  Tell me more details so that I might answer your question and solve your problem, not provide an answer based on vague statements and what I think you want that's completely different from what you intended.

Comment: He was asking "how do I add money to Minecraft". That's not even about a specific mod or method, just the basic concept. We can answer questions about the basic concept. When we *over*-estimate the asker's problem, we look equally ass-uming.

Comment: Which makes an ass out of you and Ming. Poor Ming :(

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Regardless of how you answer the question in the current state, you're making an assumption.  **That's bad!**  You need to ask the user what he wants to do.  What problem needs to be solved.  That's what I did... then promptly cast a close vote.